# How does one convey in a single phrase, the act of failing several times and succeeding finally?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

How does one convey in a single phrase, the act of failing several times and succeeding finally?

I wrote something like *"Several trials and errors later, I had found the solution"*
Is this valid usage? Is there a better way to say this?

Comment: Off topic writing advice request. Please see the [help].

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you might appreciate this quote from [Thomas Edison](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/t/thomasaed132683.html#861gy5AZlSiFPYVo.99) - "I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work."

Comment: Or this one: “Many of life's failures are people who did not realize how close they were to success when they gave up.” - Thomas Edison

Comment: I reckon the idiomatic way would be "After much trial and error, I had found a solution."

Comment: "at last!" with a very heavy sigh.

Comment: What's wrong with legitimate phrase requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- after many detours, ...
- after some false leads, ...
- after much travail, ...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *overcoming adversity*?

Comment: Adversity doesn't emphasize several failures and eventual success. :(

Comment: *Triumph over adversity*?

Comment: *Emerge victorious*?

Comment: *Snatching victory from the jaws of defeat*?

Comment: All these seem like it was a single bad thing, and not *multiple* failures. I'm going with Talia Ford's answer. Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: After these many failures, I did not succeed? I am shocked and appalled!

Comment: adversity : hardship, trial, bad luck... (Collins Thesaurus)

Comment: @TaliaFord Watch your back, TaliaFord, many failures await you and success is not assured!!!

Comment: Egad, I shall be intrepid and emerge victorious

Answer (score 1):

I blundered my way through to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I persisted through to a solution.